# Google Compute Engine - Restart at end of start up script

Tags: python, cron, google-compute-engine

Is there a good way to automatically restart an instance if it reaches the end of a start up script?

I have a Python script that I want to run continuously on Compute Engine which checks the pub/sub from a GAE instance that's running a CRON job. I haven't figured out a good way to catch every possible error and there are many edge cases that are hard to test (e.g. the instance running out of memory). It would be better if I could just restart the instance every time the script finishes (because it should never finish). The `autorestart` option won't work because the instance doesn't shutdown, it just stops running the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `shutdown -r now` may be enough.

Or if you prefer gcloud:

```
gcloud compute instances reset $(hostname)
```

Mind that `reset` is a real reset, without a proper OS shutdown.

You might also need to check [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/restarting-an-instance) documentation before performing 'Resetting or Restarting operation in an instance'

Comment: Do you mean adding `gcloud compute instances reset` at the end of the startup script?

Comment: Yes, that would do the job. But it is advisable to check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/restarting-an-instance) mentioned in the answer before performing the 'reset' action.